# How to use two bootstrap daterangepickers on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

This is code i implements daterangepicker1 with bootstrap.

```
<div class="input-group input-large custom-date-range" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="from_total"  required placeholder="Start date" id="from_total">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="to_total"   required placeholder="End date" id="to_total">
                                        </div>
```

This is the code how i implements Second daterangepicker...

```
 <div class="input-group input-large custom-date-range" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="from_owner"  placeholder="Start date" id="from_owner" >
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="to_owner" placeholder="End date" id="to_owner"  >
                                        </div>
```

Both daterangepickers are working fine, as on clicking in each input box calendar is opened and i can get values, Regarding to fields 'from_total' and 'to_total' [first two] when i select value in 'from_total' it dierectly goes to 'to_toal' that's good it's exactly what i want,,,, but problem arises in second date range picker that when i select value in 'from_owner' it doesn't goes to 'to_owner' rather cursor moves to 'to_total' that is the second input field in first daterangepicker and it's not right, i want it to move it to 'to_owner' if you have ever used TWO DATERANGEPICKERS ON A SINGLE PAGE USING BOOTSTRAP than i hope you can understand me and help as well. thanks in advance.....

Comment: You are using bootstrap version 3 date-picker??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign different id's to datepickers

```
<div class="input-group input-large custom-date-range" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="date1">
<input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="from_total"  required placeholder="Start date" id="from_total">
<span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="to_total"   required placeholder="End date" id="to_total">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-large custom-date-range" data-date="13/07/2013" data-date-    format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="date2">
<input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="from_owner"  placeholder="Start date" id="from_owner" >
<span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" name="to_owner" placeholder="End date" id="to_owner"  >
</div>
```